# Pure JavaScript/jQuery graph drawer

Tags: javascript, graphs, jquery

I'm looking for a simple pure JavaScript library which does not use canvas from HTML5 and provides drawing graphs.

Something similar to Sigma and Cytoscape Web would be perfect.

http://sigmajs.org/ (this one covers all my needs except pure JavaScript)
http://cytoscapeweb.cytoscape.org/

The library is supposed to have such features:

1. drawing nodes and edges between them (directed or not)
2. changing position of each node using drag-and-drop (not obliged but with possibility to add event listener to each node)
3. other features like highlighting edges and scaling would be big advantages too

Comment: What you mean with `does not use canvas from HTML5`? And why sigma is not a `pure Javascript` library?

Comment: If it doesn't use canvas, what are you expecting to render to? DOM elements? SVG? Why not canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), is what you want. It uses HTML5/CSS/SVG to draw. You probably want to use [Force Layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout). 
It has [drag and drop](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#drag) support and you can just style your graph with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18840/33708), d3.js should work fine. It should use SVGs for drawing, so drawing of nodes works, as does styling with CSS (see example). Here is an example from http://bl.ocks.org/jose187/4733747:

[image: simple network graph]

[`index.html`](http://bl.ocks.org/jose187/4733747#index.html):

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <meta charset="utf-8">
> <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js?2.9.3"></script>
> <style>
>
> .link {
>   stroke: #aaa;
> }
>
> .node text {
> stroke:#333;
> cursos:pointer;
> }
>
> .node circle{
> stroke:#fff;
> stroke-width:3px;
> fill:#555;
> }
>
> </style>
> <body>
> <script>
>
> var width = 960,
>     height = 500
>
> var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
>     .attr("width", width)
>     .attr("height", height);
>
> var force = d3.layout.force()
>     .gravity(.05)
>     .distance(100)
>     .charge(-100)
>     .size([width, height]);
>
> d3.json("graphFile.json", function(json) {
>   force
>       .nodes(json.nodes)
>       .links(json.links)
>       .start();
>
>   var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
>       .data(json.links)
>     .enter().append("line")
>       .attr("class", "link")
>     .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.weight); });
>
>   var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
>       .data(json.nodes)
>     .enter().append("g")
>       .attr("class", "node")
>       .call(force.drag);
>
>   node.append("circle")
>       .attr("r","5");
>
>   node.append("text")
>       .attr("dx", 12)
>       .attr("dy", ".35em")
>       .text(function(d) { return d.name });
>
>   force.on("tick", function() {
>     link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
>         .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
>         .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
>         .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
>
>     node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
>   });
> });
>
> </script>
> ```

[`graphFile.json`](http://bl.ocks.org/jose187/4733747#graphFile.json):

> ```
> {
>   "nodes":[
>       {"name":"node1","group":1},
>       {"name":"node2","group":2},
>       {"name":"node3","group":2},
>       {"name":"node4","group":3}
>   ],
>   "links":[
>       {"source":2,"target":1,"weight":1},
>       {"source":0,"target":2,"weight":3}
>   ]
> }
> ```